# Py2exe giving error

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to package the tkinter into exe app and getting the below error message. Please help.

```
setup(
 options ={'py2exe':{'bundle_files':3,'compressed':True}},
 zipfile = None,
 console = ['SApp.py'])
 To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.
 An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

 SystemExit: usage: -c [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
 or: -c --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
 or: -c --help-commands
 or: -c cmd --help

 error: option -f not recognized
```

Comment: Is this everything?  It looks like you are calling a parameter -f somewhere but it is not recognized in this context

Comment: #PyNEwbie there is no parameter -f in the code..And the code runs perfectly when run in ipython

Answer (score 0):

Try, when compiling using the flag -F instead of -f to compile to a single file.